# How can I use sbt eclipse to refresh a single sub-project in a multi-project build

Tags: sbt, sbteclipse

If I step into a project in sbt (using sbt project ) and then run the eclipse plugin, it generates .project and .classpath files for all of my projects.  How can I run it on a single project?